# http status from gsoap header

Tags: c, web-services, soap, gsoap

does anybody knows how to retrieve the http status in gSoap?

I have "HTTP/1.1 202 ACCEPTED..." and I want to print the 202 somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague, so I am going to assume a literal interpretation and that you are really asking a C question...  You say you have "HTTP/1.1 202 ACCEPTED...", and that you want to print the 202 somehow.   Here is how you would do that in C:

```
  char buf[]={"HTTP/1.1 202 ACCEPTED..."}; //create a buffer here
  char *buff; //use your own buffer with the strtok function

  buff = strtok(buf, " "); //will contain "HTTP/1.1"
  buff = strtok(NULL, " ");//will contain "202"
  printf(buff)
  getchar();
```

If this is not what you wanted, please be more specific in your question.

Regards,
Ryyker

Answer (score 0):

After the web service invocation completes you will receive an error code of 202. It's that simple. All HTTP codes except 200/400/500 are passed down to the caller "as-is", so you can catch these. Just check if the value of `soap->error == 202`.